# "Rejoicing", "glorious", and "sinuous"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Do "Rejoicing", "glorious", and "sinuous" all go to "scientists"? That is, "scientists enjoying the beauty of computer images , evolving colour patterns and multidimensional topologies, and order verging on chaos and snaking back to order again, sound ecstatic"?

Context:

Rejoicing in the beauty of computer images which show symmetries in structure and system, glorious with evolving colour patterns and multidimensional topologies, sinuous with order verging on chaos and snaking back to order again, scientists can sound ecstatic. This isn’t simply an image. It is literally the Meaning of Life. And it is beautiful. Who needs art?

(Art and Science by Sian Ede)

Comment: "glorious" and "sinuous" refer to "computer images". You could rephrase the paragraph by starting:" Scientists can sound ecstatic when they rejoice in the beauty of..."

Comment: The commas make the three adjectival phrases a compound modifier of "scientists."  But of course this is absurd even by Ede's standards.  The sense requires ignoring the first two commas, so that "Rejoicing" modifies "scientists"; "glorious" modifies "symmetries"; "sinuous" modifies "topologies."  But remember:  it's not an image.  It. Is. **Literally**. the. Meaning. of. Life.  (Oh, yeah, it's pretty too.)

Answer (score 1):

No, the *images* are "glorious" and "sinuous". The scientists are only "rejoicing".

There are some complicated layers of nested structures  here.  Let's break them down:

- **Rejoicing** in [....a.........], scientists can sound ecstatic.
- a = the beauty of  computer images which show [b.......]
- b= symmetries in structure and system (which are) [c....]
- c  = **glorious** with [d...] and [e...]
- d = evolving colour patterrns
- e = multidimensional topologies (which are) **sinuous**, with [f..]
- f = order (that is) [g..]
- g = verging on chaos and snaking back to order again

To me, it seems as if the creator of this sentence tried to structure it so as to emulate the "evolving colours", the "symmetries", the "snaking", the "order" and the "chaos", that it is trying to describe!  The sentence is perfectly grammatical (though not ideally punctuated), but it is bizarrely convoluted, even to native speakers.  No wonder it messed with your head!

Comment: _I like it, but is it English?_

Comment: English is in the eye of the beholder.  (Or is it "I know English when I see it.?)

Comment: It's a species of English -- syntactically correct but semantically empty.  George Orwell commented sixty years ago on the meaningless of the writing in this field (art criticism and literary criticism) in his essay "Politics and the English Language."

Comment: If you thought that was "semantically empty", you got off before the ride started. I found it a treat for both lobes.